# Design pattern for data structure that contains at most one item of each type

Tags: design, object-oriented-design

I have a superinterface that several different abstract classes implement: `Coverage`.

This is for insurance rating. There are several types of different coverage, and those coverages might vary by state. The "type" of coverage is an abstract class, and then the concrete implementations depend on the state where whoever buys it lives (several states generally share one of these concrete implementers).

Basically, we have

```java
public interface Coverage {/*...*/}
public abstract class Pip implements Coverage {/*...*/}
public final class FLPip extends Pip {/*...*/}
```

and then we have :

```java
public class quote {
    final List<Coverage> coverages;
    // ...
}
```

I'm thinking it would be good to have it so that adding duplicates of any of the direct implementers of `Coverage` would throw an error.

I mean, I could do something like this:

```java
abstract class Coverage {/*...*/}

abstract class Pip extends Coverage {/*...*/}

final class FLPip extends Pip {/*...*/}

class Quote {

    // ...

    private final PriorityQueue<Coverage> coverages;
    private final HashSet<Class> coverageTypes;

    // ...

    public void addCoverage(Coverage coverage) {
        Class c = coverage.getClass();
        while(c.getSuperclass() != Coverage.class)
            c = c.getSuperclass();
        if (coverageTypes.contains(c))
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        coverageTypes.add(c);
        coverages.add(coverage);
    }

    public void removeCoverage(Coverage coverage) {
        Class c = coverage.getClass();
        while(c.getSuperclass() != Coverage.class)
            c = c.getSuperclass();
        coverageTypes.remove(c);
        coverages.remove(coverage);
    }

    // ...

}
```

but this seems very "hacky" and prone to error / extensibility problems, and like I'm missing something here. Any ideas on a better pattern to use?

Comment: I guess you need this in Java?

Comment: @DanielJour it doesn't really matter. I'm just looking for a good pattern to use.

Comment: Abstract Factory.

Comment: Sidebar: I'm curious as to the use of subclasses for each state (or group of states). When the rules change, or whatever may change, for a particular state, do you have to update the code? Composition rather than inheritance might be a better choice here.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are looking for set behavior here, and indeed you are storing the "coverage types" in a `HashSet`. Could you use a `Set` to store the `Coverage` objects? If the `Coverage` implementations themselves implement `equals()` and `hashCode()`, then inserting a `Coverage` in a `Set` where it is already present would be a no-op.